# Is there a standard format for documenting function-type parameters in Sphinx using sphinx.ext.napoleon?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, type-hinting, docstring, sphinx-napoleon

I am using Sphinx to document one of my projects and one of the classes takes in a function as a parameter in its `__init__`. Is there a standard way to document this function-type parameter? I am also using [`sphinx.ext.napoleon`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/napoleon.html) to use Google formatting for my docstrings.

Here's an example:

```py
class ExampleClass:
    """An example class to demonstrate my question
    
    Args:
        func (what goes here?): Description of the parameter
    """

    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def do_something(self, param):
        """An example method

        Args:
            param (str): Description of param
        
        Returns:
            bool: The return description
        """

        return self.func(param)
```

In my code, the parameter in question should take in one `str` and return a `bool`. Is there a standard way to document this when using Sphinx?

Comment: Does this help at all? https://stackoverflow.com/q/33469924/407651

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to document the function parameter is using [`typing.Callable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#callable). By doing so the static type checker will verify that the signature (arguments and return type) of the passed function is compatible with the type hint.

```py
from typing import Callable

class ExampleClassTwo:
    """An example class to demonstrate my question.

    Args:
        func (Callable[[str], bool]): Description of the parameter.
    """
    def __init__(self, func: Callable[[str], bool]):

        self.func = func
```

However, this has one potential problem. If you look at the Python Data Model, in the [sub-section titled **"Callable types"** under *3.2 The standard type hierarchy*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy). You'll notice there are several possible types that are callables, and any callable with the specified signature would not cause a warning from the static type checker.
For example, a class instance implementing the `__call__()` method would not cause a warning:

```py
def str_function(param: str) -> bool:
    pass

class OneInstance:

    def __init__(self, param):
        pass

    def __call__(self, param: str) -> bool:
        pass

one_instance = OneInstance("test instance")
# neither of the below raise a static type check warning
one = ExampleClassTwo(str_function)
two = ExampleClassTwo(one_instance)
```

You can type hint the `param` signature as shown above together with validating that `param` is of type [`FunctionType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.FunctionType)  in the `__init__`  as you would validate other parameters at run-time, and raise a `TypeError` exception if the parameter is not a function.

```py
from typing import Callable
from types import FunctionType

class ExampleClassTwo:
    """An example class to demonstrate my question

    Args:
        func (Callable[[str], bool]): Description of the parameter
    Raises:
        TypeError: Argument `param` is not of type ``FunctionType``.
    """

    def __init__(self, func: Callable[[str], bool]):

        if type(func) in (FunctionType,):
            self.func = func
        else:
            raise TypeError("param must be initialized as being of ``FunctionType``.")
```

It may be possible to combine both requirements `Callable[[str], bool]` and `FunctionType` as [an intersection using structural subtyping](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/#unions-and-intersections-of-protocols), I have not yet tried that approach.

Finally some examples are included that would cause the static type checker to raise warnings:

```py
def int_function(param: int) -> bool:
    pass


class ExampleClass:
    """An example class to demonstrate my question

    Args:
        func (FunctionType): Description of the parameter
    """

    def __init__(self, func: FunctionType):
        self.func = func

three = ExampleClass(str_function("test string"))  # Expected type 'FunctionType', got 'bool' instead
four = ExampleClass(str_function)  # Expected type 'FunctionType', got '(param: str) -> bool' instead
five = ExampleClass(type(str_function))  # No warning five.func is {type} <class 'function'>

six = ExampleClassTwo(int_function(2))  # Expected type '(str) -> bool', got 'bool' instead
seven = ExampleClassTwo(str_function("test string"))  # Expected type '(str) -> bool', got 'bool' instead
eight = ExampleClassTwo(int_function)  # Expected type '(str) -> bool', got '(param: int) -> bool' instead
nine = ExampleClassTwo(str_function)  # No warning
```

[image]